# define theano function with other theano function output

Tags: function, theano

I am new to theano, can anyone help me defining a theano function like this:

Basically, I have a network model looks like this:

```
y_hat, cost, mu, output_hiddens, cells = nn_f(x, y, in_size, out_size, hidden_size, layer_models, 'MDN', training=False)
```

here the input x is a tensor:

```
x = tensor.tensor3('features', dtype=theano.config.floatX)
```

I want to define two theano functions for later use:

```
f_x_hidden = theano.function([x], [output_hiddens])

f_hidden_mu = theano.function([output_hiddens], [mu], on_unused_input = 'warn')
```

the first one is fine. for the second one, the problem is both the input and the output are output of the original function. it gives me error:

> theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: An input of the graph, used to compute Elemwise{identity}(features), was not provided and not given a value.

my understanding is, both of `[output_hiddens]` and `[mu]` are related to the input `[x]`, there should be an relation between them. I tried define another `theano` function from `[x]` to `[mu]` like:

```
f_x_mu = theano.function([x], [mu]),
```

then

```
f_hidden_mu = theano.function(f_x_hidden, f_x_mu),
```

but it still does not work. Does anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is NO WAY. In [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#basictutexamples)

> Because in Theano you first express everything symbolically and afterwards compile this expression to get functions, ...

You can't use the output of `theano.function` as input/output for another `theano.function` since they are already a compiled graph/function.

You should pass the symbolic variables, such as x in your example code for `f_x_hidden`, to build the model.